# Keypress is not working

Tags: jquery

This is my code. someone has already asked this question still that solution doesn't work for me. please provide a solution

```
$('#appDB').keydown(function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if (keycode == '32') {
        alert('You pressed a "space" key in textbox');  
    }
});
```

Comment: There's no reason this shouldn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/h8hcdngp/. Can you please post an example of your exact problem.

Comment: Its working fine without any problem http://jsfiddle.net/gxbzLra4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working without any problem , you may missing jQuery library

```js
$('#appDB').keydown(function(event) {
  var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
  if (keycode == '32') {
    alert('You pressed a "space" key in textbox');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="appDB"/>
```

Include jQuery library by adding `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before your script.